# Misunderstanding how to use MarshalJSON

Tags: json, go

I have a rather unusual situation.  I want MarshalJSON to conditionally omit a struct field.  In the example below, the idea is to omit output of the `B Bool` field if `B.Value == B.Undefined`.

```golang
type Bool struct {
    // Current value
    Value bool
    // Value if undefined
    Undefined bool
}

func (b Bool) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if b.Value == b.Undefined {
        return []byte{}, nil
    } else if b.Value {
        return ([]byte)("true"), nil
    }
    return ([]byte)("false"), nil
}

func main() {
    var example = struct {
        N int  `json:"foo"`
        B Bool `json:"value,omitempty"`
    }
    example.B = Bool{true, true}
    output, err := json.Marshal(example)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/K83-uR0QSSg)

According to the docs:

> The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from
>   the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a
>   nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map,
>   or string.

I return an empty byte slice, which results in an error:

```
panic: json: error calling MarshalJSON for type main.Bool: unexpected end of JSON input

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox933539113/prog.go:32 +0x160
```

If I set `example.B = Bool{false, true}`, then it prints the result, but the field still isn't omitted, despite returning `"false"` from `Bool.MarshalJSON`.  What am I doing wrong?  Does a value with a type satisfying the `Marshaler` interface effectively ignore the omitempty tag entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```golang
 if b.Value == b.Undefined {
        return []byte{}, nil
```

produces invalid JSON: it returns 0 bytes. Your `MarshalJSON` method *must* return valid JSON, which means it must return *something*.

If your goal is to omit that field entirely, when it's not set, use a pointer, and don't set it:

```golang
func main() {
    var example = struct {
        N int   `json:"foo"`
        B *Bool `json:"value,omitempty"`
    }
    example.B = Bool{N: true, B: nil}
    output, err := json.Marshal(example)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(output))
}
```

If you want to omit that field entirely when the value of `Bool` is a particular value, then you must define your `MarshalJSON` method on the containing struct, so that it can properly omit the field when desired.

Comment: Makes sense, though it still seems a bit counterintuitive. I guess I'll create a separate `IsZeroer` interface and call the `IsZero` method of any instances in the parent struct's `MarshalJSON` method. Thank you for the help.